# How could I resubmit a game in google play console?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

Last week I submitted a game and google play team rejected it because of lack of privacy policy. I made a privacy policy and also changed my game to be appropriate for family.
In google play console are some options to change games descriptions and screen shots and etc, to resubmit. But I couldn't replace my new aab file. Should I submit it again, from the beginning? 
Please help me.

Comment: What about asking their customer service?

Comment: if you changed something in code then obviously you will need to resubmit  APK/AAB file to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check your email with the specific account if they have the advice to upload aab/apk and resubmit to App. The yes replace aab/apk with version code up.
2. Please check they advice to changes the **privacy policy, content rating, app content** then no need to changes in aab/apk only resubmit the app after change above all three things.

Comment: Thanks. But they asked me to provide  the privacy policy and choose accurate age rate, so I had to change my app to be appropriate for family and children. But know I don't know I should replace it (and how? ) or resubmit it again from the beginning? Also I sent an email to google costumer service, but they don't answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I find out : Release management > App release > Production track > Manage > Edit release